# Using CSS3 or Jquery for logo text decoration?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to use CSS to do this. http://snag.gy/nBgU1.jpg  I keep running into things that just won't let me do it and look good while also allowing the whole logo to scale using fittext.js.  My problems, I can't use underline since I have to specify pixels so it's not responsive anymore, have been using other solutions, but they're getting messy thanks to letter spacing.  So, I guess my question is, at what point do I give up trying to use CSS and use JS or images?  I'm only mediocre at this stuff, so I'm not really sure.

Comment: Try not ask open ended questions like you did. "my question is, at what point do I give up trying to use CSS and use JS or images?" Ask about how to get something done instead of people's opinion.

Comment: Is it not ok to ask for opinions on here?  I want to learn why I should do things a certain way and not just how to do it.

Comment: No not really. That is why your question is on hold... and minus votes.

Comment: Well, an opinion was what I was after, so my post solved nothing for me.  I gave credit to a person who at least tried to answer the question, eventhough, it still didn't do what I wanted b/c of the issues with letter spacing.  The minus vote is b/c I thought upvoting it myself would help get some visibility, so they gave me a minus instead of just not upvoting it.  That's not really how it works on other sites. So, it was just a waste of a post all around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve it using a border. Here is a [really hasty demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JnyR6/).

```
<div><span>Example</span> Thing</div>
```

And CSS:

```
div {
    font-size: 3em;
}

span {
    font-size: 0.7em;
    border-bottom: 0.3em solid black;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for an actual comment instead of an "I'm doing it wrong comment".  I'm going to see if I can get letter spacing to work w/ this.  I was trying to use percentages, but I guess ems is a better fit for this.